# In mozilla, text-overflow:ellipsis not working

Tags: css, ellipsis

I have used a jquery plugin for getting ellipsis in mozilla but I want to know other methods to get the ellipsis because the plugin I have used showing script error in some cases.
/***************edited*********************/
I have used the plugin

```
jquery.text-overflow.js
```

And the script error ask to disable script in the page

Comment: Hi! Could you post the code you used, the url of the plugin you tried, and which error message you are getting, and in which line?

Comment: please find the updated portion

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think your best bet will be to follow @Spudley's link and use the workaround detailed in his post, this seems to be the cleanest way to do this. Good luck!

Comment: yes link that Spudley gave helped me to solve my issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firefox / Mozilla does not currently support `text-overflow:ellipsis;`

There is a work-around - see this question on SO for a detailed answer: [how to obtain Text-overflow : ellipsis type style (...) in mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625329/how-to-obtain-text-overflow-ellipsis-type-style-in-mozilla/4625849#4625849)

[EDIT]

Since people are still up-voting this old answer, I'm adding this note to point out that this feature was added in Firefox 7, so is now irrelevant for most users. There are still a few FF3.6 users out there that this will apply to, but for most of us, it's no longer an issue.

Comment: @Poornima - just so you know, Firefox v4 will still not support ellipsis, but also the work around no longer works. No solution yet, but still looking (see my question here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927257/text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-4)

Comment: `text-overflow:ellipsis;` just made it into Aurora, meaning it should be in Firefox by Firefox 7! http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/07/aurora7/