# CSS text over flow why isn't this working

Tags: css

I want the text in the header to be shortned with ellipses. but it doesn't the whole address shows in one line

```
<table border="0" style="font-weight:normal; position: absolute; top:45; left: 0;">      
    <th align="left" style="" width="10%">
         <span style=" overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; width:10px; font-weight:normal; white;" 
                onclick="dropdownResize()"><i>Address</i> &nbsp; <b>${bean.address}</b></span>
    </th>
     <tr >
      <td style=" border-style:solid; border-width:0px; text-transform:capitalize; text-indent:1px;">
    </br>
    <br>Usual address <br><b>${bean.address}</b></br> <br> 
    </td>       
     </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of stuff wrong with your code,

For a start you are using `<b>` `<i>` as well as using `<table>`s to layout your content (which is by the way a bad practise) AND you are using `<br> </br>` which aren't even real tags - the tag you are looking for is `<br/>` - It is a self closing tag as it can never contain any arguments or content.

The `<span>` tags you have chose to use do not support the `width` parameter as they just wrap the text that is contained within them and as such I have changed this to a `<div>` and changed all your `<b>` and `<i>` tags to `<span>` tags with CSS `classes` attached to them.

I have fixed up your coding here:

[### Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q4CqZ/9/)

As for your table layout I suggest you read a few of these:

http://shouldiusetablesforlayout.com/

http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/

http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3642151/CSS-Layouts-Without-Tables.htm

Next up, support:

FF4 does not support the `text-overflow:ellipsis` as it used to in FF3.6 via a hack, see here for further info:

[text-overflow:ellipsis in Firefox 4? (and FF5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927257/text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-4)

Answer (score 2):

You're using a `<span>` which by default is an inline element and cannot receive width, height, etc like block level elements.

To change this, either use a div or add `display: block;` to your span's style.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `display:block` to the style on the `span` tag.

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure you test it in supported browsers:** [**http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html)

Firefox doesn't support ellipsis.

Comment: For current versions of Firefox, there is a hack that can work-around this and allow you to support ellipsis, but FF4 will remove the feature that allows the hack, so it's a bit of a step backward. See also my current question here on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927257/text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-4