# How do I display only the first 10 characters from a string using CSS?

Tags: css

I have a string of 30 characters

I want to only display the first 10 followed by ...

so for example

---

**thisisastringthatis30characterslong**

would become

**thisisastr...**

---

Is this possible using CSS?

Cheers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It´s called [ellipsis](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html) and you can use it on a block element.

However it does not work in Firefox and you cannot set the width to exactly 10 characters as you cannot specify the width in characters in css.

If you want exactly 10 characters and Firefox compatibility you will have to use javascript or a server-side solution.

Comment: that's awesome - I need this kind of functionality quite a lot - I had never bothered to ask if it existed because I subsumed that it wouldn't. Nice to know about it.

Comment: Cool cheers for that, ill just use a preg_match on the first ten characters and then add on the ...      thanks again

Answer (score 8):

There is a [CSS3 based solution](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp) `text-overflow:ellipsis;` claimed to be crossbrowser. But also it will show as many chars as fit, not exactly 10.

Comment: It seems that will stop working in Firefox 4: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927257/text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-4

Answer (score 0):

```
#containerx {
     display: block;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     max-width: 60%;
}
```

by adjusting the width you can control number of characters to display