# What are the differences between Fx 3.x and Fx 4.x that made many userscripts stop working?

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey, userscripts

[I develop scripts](http://userscripts.org/users/55607) for userscripts.org and just upgraded my fx from 3.6.16 to 4.0, but many scripts of mine stopped working with the following message error:

```
Error: Component returned failure code: 0x8007000e (NS_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY) [nsIXPCComponents_Utils.evalInSandbox]
Source code: file:///xxx.user.js
```

I know this message means some kind of "infinite" process, but it doesn't appear any line number that can help me to figure it out.

Any help/answer/link is welcome.

**Operating System:** Windows 7 64-bit
**Greasemonkey version:** 0.9.1
**Example of script that is not working:**
[Userscripts : Beautifier + Deobfuscator](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/58687) target: http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/58687
(I will add more examples as soon as I get back home from work)

**Other sources that made me think about the problem:**
[Lots of scripts no longer working?](http://userscripts.org/topics/70673?page=1#posts-329952)

Comment: Got an example script with fewer dependencies?  Six requires and 2 resources!! That's more than I'm willing to div into, at the moment.

Comment: You only need the following requires: 63808, 87269 and beautify.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Firefox 4, you can't use RegExp as a loop condition because a new instance will be created for each iteration, causing the infinite loop. (lastIndex = 0)

```
while (/.../g.exec("...")) {  // used to work
    /* your code goes here */
}
```

To prevent this from happening, create a separate variable with the RegExp:

```
var re = /.../g;
while (re.exec("...")) {  // works perfectly
    /* your code goes here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only feature I know of that's been removed in Firefox 4 is the ability to use XUL directly within a web page (ie using the `-moz-binding` CSS style).

I don't know if that's what's affected your scripts. It has affected one fairly well-known Firefox hack (see [text-overflow:ellipsis in Firefox 4? (and FF5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927257/text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-4)), but I wasn't aware of any other impact of this change.