# Better solution to regex.exec() assignment in while loop

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there any better solution to this here? I try to avoid the assignment inside `while` but still be able to loop through the matches and use the captured groups.

```
var match = "";
var CSS_URL_PATTERN = /url\s*\(\s*["|']?(.*?)\s*["|']?\)\s*/gm
while ((match = CSS_URL_PATTERN.exec(someBigCSSString)) !== null) {
   // Do stuff here per match…
}
```

I added a bit more context to this question, also a RegEx example.

Comment: Why not use `match`. It will return an array which you can loop. You way you designed it now will be an endless loop.

Comment: What are you trying to do in this loop?

Comment: *"avoid the assignment inside while"* - why? you can avoid it but it's really not that bad.

Comment: It won't work properly whether it has `g` flag. In this case, it should be assigned outside loop.

Comment: @dfsq Not sure about that. The only reason I can think of is that the assignment '=' can be easily misread with a comparison '==='. It simply doesn't feel right tbh and ESLint complains about it (no-cond-assign).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always do as follows when I need `.exec`:

```
var re = /.../g, match;
while (match = re.exec(...)) {
    //...
}
```

Regular expressions with `g` flag causes infinite effect when it is in the loop condition.

[What are the differences between Fx 3.x and Fx 4.x that made many userscripts stop working?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18708778/157873)

Comment: Aye … I have the regex declaration outside of the loop. Amended my question for clarity.

Comment: @wittgenstein, my answer is still the same. I don't think there any better and shorter way to do what you want without missing legibility.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid the assignment inside `while` you can use a `do while` loop:

```
var URLRegExp = /url\s*\(\s*["|']?(.*?)\s*["|']?\)\s*/g
var match
do {
  match = URLRegExp.exec(bootstrap)
  if (match) {
    // Do stuff here per match...
  }
} while (match)
```

But a `while loop` it's simpler and avoids unnecesary code like the `if` statement inside `do`. An assignment inside a condition is not as bad as people think if you understand what's the behaviour of the code and what's the context.

Another case is when you're using a linter to avoid to mistype a comparison operator (such as ==) as an assignment operator, but allmost all the linters using now support using comments to modify linter behaviour in a specific part of the code so this isn't really a problem

Comment: nice! you can also break on no match `if (!match) break;`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var match = "Is This The Real Life|Is This Just Fantasy|Caught In A Landslide|No Escape From Reality|".match(/.+?\|/ig);

//print result using join
document.body.innerHTML += match.join("<br />");
document.body.innerHTML += "<br /><br />";
//print results using for loop and strip |
for (var i = 0; i < match.length; ++i)
{
    document.body.innerHTML += match[i].slice(0, -1) + "<br />";
}
```

This will avoid a loop altogether. `match` returns an array. You can either loop it and do stuff with it, or like I did print the results using join. `match` accepts `regex-patterns`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var matches = someString.match(REGEX_PATTERN);
for (var i = 0; matches && i < matches.length; i++) {
  // Do stuff here per match…
}
```

Comment: If REGEX_PATTERN needs to capture groups and the global flag is set, you need to use `RegExp.exec()`

Comment: @w35l3y didn't realize that. TIL. The question says nothing about what he needs to do though...

Comment: @w35l3y Exactly. I added the regex to the question. Sorry, I missed it when I originally posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
someString.replace(REGEX_PATTERN,
    function (wholeMatch, group1, group2/*...*/, index, sourceString) {
        // Do stuff here per match…
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[In 2023](https://caniuse.com/?search=matchall) [String.prototype.matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) works as an alternative to the while loop:

```js
const CSS_URL_PATTERN = /url\s*\(\s*["|']?(.*?)\s*["|']?\)\s*/gm
[...someBigCSSString.matchAll(CSS_URL_PATTERN)].forEach(match => {
  // Do stuff here per match…
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A few years later...

```
const URLRegExp = /url\s*\(\s*["|']?(.*?)\s*["|']?\)\s*/g;
for (;;) {
  const match = URLRegExp.exec(bootstrap);
  if (!match) break;
    // Use the match
  }
}
```