# jquery - find if element is overflowing its container

Tags: jquery

Using **Jquery**, how to I find out if an element is overflowing its container ?

> `<div style="overflow:hidden"><label>My really really long label</label></div>`

I would like to know when the text of the label is being cutoff so that I can act on it.

Thank you

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668636/check-with-jquery-if-div-has-overflowing-elements/7668730#7668730

Comment: yes I looked at it unfortunately the accepted answer does not use jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [width function](http://api.jquery.com/width/) to check if the `<label>` is longer than the `<div>`:

```
if($('label').width() > $('div').width()){
   // longer element 
}
```

Here's a [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/hZBj5/).