# Get non visible inner div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a div(parentDivStyle) with position `absolute` which is my parent div. Then I have 5 children(childDivStyle) div inside the parent div with position `relative`. I have set the `overflow` to hidden of the parent div. So some of the child divs are not visible. I would like to get the divs which are not visible by jquery. Is there any way?

I have googled it and most of the results where related to "visible" property, That is not what I want. And also I am not preferring any plugin. Any help please.

**CSS**

```
.parentDivStyle {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    background:#ccc;
    float:left;
}
.childDivStyle {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    background:red;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parentDivStyle">
<div class="childDivStyle">1</div>
<div class="childDivStyle">2</div>
<div class="childDivStyle">3</div>
<div class="childDivStyle">4</div>
<div class="childDivStyle">5</div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/3suDz/1/)

Comment: Why do you have a height set on the parent, along with overflow: hidden, if you want the children to be visible? It's not really clear what you are doing here.

Comment: @ralph.m, I am building a slider. An I need to know the non visible divs.

Comment: Do you want to display all the `.childDivStyle` that are not visible or simply show one at a time (think of a sprite image)?

Comment: why not use a ready made one - there are millions of free ones out there

Comment: @MarcAudet no, I want to just identify the non visible ones

Comment: @Pete, sorry to say this sir, but am not really allowed to use any external library.

Comment: jquery is an external library?

Comment: @arjuncc have a look at jCarouselLite, http://gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/, even if you're not allowed to use it, you could rip it off without remorse.

Comment: @Pete, Sir, we have special permission for certain libraries, which are trusted by the client.

Comment: In your fiddle, div-1 and div-2 are visible by design, so you want to shift the list over so div-2 and div-3, then div-3 and div-4 are visible?

Comment: @MarcAudet . Sorry to say. Am not the decision maker. :( . Its a task assigned :(

Comment: @MarcAudet Yea, I need that divs which are not visible in the view port.

Comment: So, ideally, you want some type of a selector that would return, in your example, div-3, div-4 and div-5, maybe as a jQuery object?

Comment: @MarcAudet, selector or a java script method comparing the positions.

Comment: not sure what you need to check the visibility for but if you need a slider without using an external library I would make it like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/5nW53/. if you are wanting to continue down the finding if a div is visible or not, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668636/check-with-jquery-if-div-has-overflowing-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11396681/693542) about getting coordinates of elements, you can figure out where elements are in respect to each other.  Once you know the coordinates of the visible area, you can easily figure out what child elements are visible.

This will tell you whether the elements are visible, and if not, which direction they are with respects to the container.

```
displayCoords = function(element) {
    var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left);   

    var childElements = element.children;
    for(i = 0; i < childElements.length; i++)
    {
        childRect = childElements[i].getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log(childRect.top, childRect.right, childRect.bottom, childRect.left);  
        if(childRect.top >=  rect.bottom)
            console.log("not visible -- off the bottom of element");
        else if(childRect.left >= rect.right)
            console.log("not visible -- off the right of element");
        else if(childRect.bottom <= rect.top)
            console.log("not visible -- off the top of element");
        else if(childRect.right <= rect.left)
            console.log("not visible -- off the left of element");
    }

}
```

I forked your JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hJdnk/3/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the position of the child divs, and the height of the parent like this:

```
$('#parent .childDivStyle').each(function(index,div){
    if($(div).position().top > $('#parent').height()) alert($(div).html())
});
```

The working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3suDz/3/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice answer, but I have to consider even if it is aligned rightwise or left wise. am adding +1

Comment: This is not fool proof since it depends on the precise geometry of the layout. For example, if you set the black border with to 0px, then you get different results.  However, the idea is good but the implementation demands precision.

Comment: I would recommend using a combination of [outerWidth(true)](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) and [outerHeight(true)](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) so that the padding, border, and margins are included in dimension calculations as well.

Comment: You can use $(div).position().left, $(div).width() and $('#parent').width() to test for right and left align

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
$('div.parentDivStyle div').each(function(index, element){
            alert(this.offsetTop + $(this).height() > $('div.parentDivStyle').height());
        });
```

if child div is hidden then it will return true else false.

Check on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3suDz/4/

Comment: This seems to work well.  I tweaked the HTML, for example, set border to 0px, vary the width of `.parentDivStyle` and the true/false value was accurate.  This looks pretty robust.  Please explain `this.offsetTop`, thank-you.

Comment: it will return the distance of the current child element relative to the top of the parent node.

http://help.dottoro.com/ljnvukbb.php

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle that takes into account the relative nature of the child divs.  It can be condensed, but I left it in long-form so the logic is apparent

http://jsfiddle.net/arpTx/18/

```
$("#p").children().each(
        function(idx, el) { 
            var pos = $(el).position();

            console.log("child " + $(el).text() + " is visible: " + isVisible(pos.left, pos.top));
    });

function isVisible(x, y) {
    var pos = $("#p").position();
    var left = pos.left;
    var right = left + $("#p").width();
    var top = pos.top;
    var bottom = top + $("#p").height();    

    x += left;
    y += top;
    return (x >= left && x < right) && (y >= top && y < bottom); }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this as a solution

CSS

```
.parentDivStyle {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    background:#ccc;
    float:left;
}
.childDivStyle {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    background:red;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="parent" class="parentDivStyle">
    <div class="childDivStyle">1</div>
    <div class="childDivStyle">2</div>
    <div class="childDivStyle">3</div>
    <div class="childDivStyle">4</div>
    <div class="childDivStyle">5</div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function getNotVisible(parentId, childClassName) {
    var parent = document.getElementById(parentId),
        children,
        elements;

    if (parent) {
        children = parent.getElementsByClassName(childClassName);
        if (children) {
            elements = [];
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(children, function (child) {
                var pBounds = parent.getBoundingClientRect(),
                    cBounds = child.getBoundingClientRect();

                if (cBounds.right < pBounds.left || cBounds.left > pBounds.right || cBounds.bottom < pBounds.top || cBounds.top > pBounds.bottom) {
                    elements.push(child);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    return elements;
}

console.log(getNotVisible("parent", "childDivStyle"));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/7RAtw/)

BTW, if you want a jquery object from this then do the following

```
var $hiddens = $(getNotVisible("parent", "childDivStyle"));
```

Also, if you want an array returned rather than undefined, i.e. silently fail if the parent element is not or no children are found.

Then delete

```
elements = [];
```

And change

```
var parent = document.getElementById(parentId),
    children,
    elements = [];
```

And of course this all depends on you setting your CSS correctly, as no checks are being made for `visibility` or `overflow`, etc.

If you want to add CSS checks, to double check your CSS work, then you can use [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) and check the important values.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery's is() function, like so:

```
$(element).is(":visible")
```

So in your case, you would do something like this:

```
var elems = $(".childDivStyle");
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
{
    if(!($(elems[i]).is(":visible")))
    {
        // The element is hidden
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not quite work as you might expect since all the `.childDivStyle` elements are visible, which is different from being hidden because of the overflow property setting.  See http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/3suDz/5/