# Is there a CSS selector that will select elements with overflowing text?

Tags: css-selectors, css

Is it possible to write a css selector that only selects elements where the text-overflow behavior has been invoked?

```
<div style="width: 200px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
I don't want to select this
</div>

<div style="width: 200px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
But I do want to select this because it's overflowing
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7UNJ/)

Comment: I think you'll need javascript for this. Here's a similar post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668636/check-with-jquery-if-div-has-overflowing-elements

Comment: No, there isn't. But depending on exactly what you want to do with the overflow, there might be another way to achieve it.

Comment: @Spudley - I'm trying to build a non-native tooltip style for text blocks.  I just wanted to see if there was a CSS selector I could use before I went the Javascript route.

Comment: what I've done in the past with this sort of thing is use `:hover` to change the element when you mouse over it so that the overflow is visible, and give it some additional styling like border and background. I guess this is the kind of thing you're thinking of? You can't differentiate between ones that have overflowed and ones that haven't, but the effect works equally well for either.

Comment: That's basically what I ended up doing, as well.  It's one of those things that I've done several times before, but I always end up trying to do it differently this time :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No there's no CSS selector with which you can select elements where overflow occurs.

Comment: There's a proposal to add it, but it probably won't happen: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2011 . As a workaround, maybe "overflow" event will become widely adopted someday: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/overflow_event