# CSS has-scrollbar selector? Target elements with visible scrollbars only

Tags: html, css

I want to target elements which have a visible scrollbar using only CSS. Is this possible without javascript?

For example, If I have 3 divs styled with `overflow-y:auto`, How do I change the styles for them only when their scrollbar has appeared?

Comment: I don't think this is possible but I'd like to be proved wrong

Comment: I think this is similar to question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865167/is-there-a-css-selector-that-will-select-elements-with-overflowing-text), It does not seem possible using CSS only

Comment: Not with pure CSS. I know you said no JS, but this might be useful if you change your mind http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814398/how-can-i-check-if-a-scrollbar-is-visible

Comment: I suppose it wouldn't be possible to style elements depending if there is a scrollbar or not. Consider the scenario where when you have a scrollbar you you alter the height of the elements inside so the scrollbar is removed, then they get to their original height, the scrollbar appears and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's not possible without javascript**

However it only requires a single line of JS to toggle a CSS class on when the scrollbar is visible:

```
el.classList.toggle("scrollbarOn", el.scrollHeight > el.clientHeight)
```

**Here's a demo:**

```js
//toggles a class on an element when the scrollbar is visible:
function updScrollClass(el) {
  return el.classList.toggle("scrollbarOn", el.scrollHeight > el.clientHeight)
}
//changes the height of myDiv every second:
setInterval(function(){
  var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv')
  myDiv.classList.toggle('tall')
  updScrollClass(myDiv)
},1000)
```

```css
#myDiv{ 
  width:150px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
}

#myDiv.tall{
  height:300px;
}

.scrollbarOn{ 
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id='myDiv' class='tall'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc convallis nisl in accumsan porta. Etiam in urna orci. Vestibulum elementum, velit ac vestibulum efficitur, est elit auctor massa, nec porta ante nunc eget tellus. Integer eu ligula felis. 
</div>
```

Answer (score 16):

CSS does not cover this selection. You need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

With pure CSS I doubt it but it doesn't require a lot of javascript code either, look at this example:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(el => {
  if (el.offsetHeight > document.documentElement.offsetHeight) {
      console.log('I am higher than my father: ', el);
      el.classList.add('higher-class');
  }
});
```

```css
.higher-class {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="height:50px;">
  <div class="some-child"  style="height:100px;font-size: 5rem">
    Higher element
  </div>
</div>
```

#### check

- offsetHeight property:

  - https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight
- And the classList property:

  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score -1):

Is not a specific CSS selector that directly targets elements with visible scrollbars. However, you can achieve a similar effect using a combination of pseudo-classes and sibling selectors.

Here's an example using the `:hover` pseudo-class to target elements only when their scrollbar is being interacted with:

```
/* Initially, style the element with overflow-y: auto */
div {
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Your other styles */
}

/* When the scrollbar is being hovered */
div:hover {
  /* Apply styles for when the scrollbar is visible */
  /* For example, you could increase the width of the container */
  width: 150%;
}
```

This example assumes that you want to change styles when the scrollbar is being hovered. If you want to apply styles only when the scrollbar is always visible (not just during interaction), there's no pure CSS solution as of my last update. JavaScript would be needed to dynamically check whether the scrollbar is visible and apply styles accordingly.

Here's a JavaScript example using the `offsetHeight` and `clientHeight` properties to determine scrollbar visibility:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');

  elements.forEach(function (element) {
    if (element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight) {
      // Apply styles for visible scrollbar
      element.classList.add('visible-scrollbar');
    }
  });
});
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
.visible-scrollbar {
  /* Styles for elements with visible scrollbar */
  /* For example, you could increase the width of the container */
  width: 150%;
}
```