# Add border to div only if it's scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css, razor

I have a div in a view that I only want to show scrollbars for it if it overflows. I also want to show the borders, but only if it overflows.

I have the scrollbar part figured out using a CSS class

```
.conditional-scrollbars {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Is there a way to only show the div borders if it overflows?

Is there an event that fires when the scrollbars are made visible?

Comment: This doesn't seem possible with CSS alone: [CSS has-scrollbar selector? Target elements with visible scrollbars only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114800/css-has-scrollbar-selector-target-elements-with-visible-scrollbars-only)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a scrollbar is visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814398/how-can-i-check-if-a-scrollbar-is-visible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that worked. I added this function to a js file

```
// function to determine if an element has scrollbars 
(function ($) {
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function () {
        return this.get(0) ? this.get(0).scrollHeight > this.innerHeight() : false;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Then I just check the element after it has been populated. If the hasScrollBar function returns true, I add borders to the element via a css class.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of [Adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48176759/4760460). You can add a border based on the `height` of the `div`. Here is the code I added from [Adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48176759/4760460):

```
if ($('.conditional-scrollbars').height() >= 100) {
    $('.conditional-scrollbars').css('border', '2px solid #ddd')
}
```

You can remove the border in the same type of manner.

```js
$('#addTxt').on('click', () => {
    $('.conditional-scrollbars').append('<p>Hello world!</p>');
 if ($('.conditional-scrollbars').height() >= 100) {
     $('.conditional-scrollbars').css('border', '2px solid #ddd')
    }
});
```

```css
.conditional-scrollbars {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    max-width:100px;
    max-height:100px;
    
    /* for demo */
    min-width: 50px;
    padding: 2px;
}
p {
    margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="conditional-scrollbars"></div>
<button id="addTxt">add text</button>
```