# Is there anyway to check if an element has overflowed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, yui

My site has numerous horizontal lists of words.  If the row has too many words to display in one row, it needs to display an "expand" button.  Right now I determine if the row is full by adding up the estimated widths of the letters, but I am wondering if there is a simpler way to do this.  Is there any way using javascript or any library (especially YUI or jQuery) to determine if an element has overflow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668636/check-with-jquery-if-div-has-overflowing-elements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're referring to the overflow css property of DOM nodes. In that case you could compare the scrollWidth as opposed to the clientWidth.

[Understanding offsetWidth, clientWidth, scrollWidth and -Height, respectively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064101/understanding-offsetwidth-clientwidth-scrollwidth-and-height-respectively)

Comment: In most cases, detecting overflow should be done comparing `clientHeight` and `scrollHeight` rather than width.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but out of curiosity, what if the content doesn't overflow on the height? I believe the question referred to widths...

Comment: I guess it depends on the CSS implementation, but if the OP is using `float:left` or something similar the content will overflow vertically not horizontally...so why not check *both*?

Comment: scroll-height only tells me if I have elements out of view if the container has overflow:scroll, correct?  I don't want to scroll in the container, I want to know if there are elements that are hidden because they do not fit.  As far as I can tell, scrollHeight = clientHeight if there is no scrollbar.

Comment: Nevermind, I realized that they appeared to be equal because I was only checking before I added the element that made them not equal.  I'm able to do exactly what I want to do now.  Thanks!