# Div with fixed height and big text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with fixed with and height and a big text. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/gEjTz/  I want to reseze text to appear in this div. How to do this? Thanks!

```
<div style="height: 20px; border: 1px solid black;">
    <span style="display: inline-block; font-size: 50px;">This is my text that I want to fit ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss s</span>
</div>
$(function() {
    var span = $('span');
    var fontSize = parseInt(span.css('font-size'));

    do {
        fontSize--;
        span.css('font-size', fontSize.toString() + 'px');
    } while (span.height() >= 20);
});
```

Comment: Its not 100% clear what you want, can you give an example of expected output?

Comment: You wish to change font-size to match div width and height? or change div's sizes?

Comment: Try to lower the `font-size:50px;`?

Comment: I want to fit the text in this div. For now, it appears  under my div.

Comment: Add a width to the div. Thats will solve it!

Comment: I added but my text appear under my div.

Comment: It is quite unclear what are you asking.

Comment: I have a div with fixed height and width and inside i have a text that is changing, and sometimes it can be word or two and sometimes it can be a sentence. What i need is to shrink font size so it fit to that div.

Comment: from a UI point of view, you would be better off allowing scroll on the div and keeping the font-size constant ...

Comment: Side note: Please be careful with code like `do { fontSize-- } while (span.height() > 20)` because in certain circumstances (particularly when text is zoomed, in zoom-text-only mode in Firefox) it can result in an endless loop (with fontSize going down from 0 towards negative infinity). I've seen it once on some webpage and it crashed my browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't know if you wanted to keep that `span` ... i set it up to work without that ... sorry if you needed it

using an idea from [Check with jquery if div has overflowing elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668636/check-with-jquery-if-div-has-overflowing-elements), i've set this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wsJm6/1/) for you.

you just need to check if the element overflow is triggered, and while that happens reduce the `font-size`.

But for the user's sake, i would suggest you keep a constant font size and add `overflow: auto;` to the parent `div`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have fixed dimensions of the box, you cant set the `font-size`. If you want to set the `font-size`, you cant set dimensions.
you need to do this:

```
<div style="display:inline; border: 1px solid black;">
<span style="font-size: 50px;">This is my text that I want to fit ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss s</span>
```

**Watch here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gEjTz/435/)**

**EDIT:**
**[JSFiddle changed](http://jsfiddle.net/gEjTz/437/)**

Comment: that's not fixed width and height

Comment: but why you want them fixed?

Comment: i don't. but she does. she said so in the comments on the question