# How to Delete First Word from <li> if the text overflows from it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to delete the first word from my `<li>` only if the text overflows from it.

[Here is my nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3bcQ.jpg)

Any ideas?

Here is my code.

```
<div class="box-heading box-sections box-block">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul id="menu">
            <?php foreach ($products as $product){ ?>
            <li><a href="#Section<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want my `<li>` to show ANIMALS, CARS, CITYSCAPE and delete "CUSTOM" from it.

Comment: Could you also post relevant CSS code or create a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)**?

Comment: http://metalwallart.ca/index.php?route=product/customcategory&path=165

This is the link that I intend to do.

Comment: For CARS the li did not overflow...? do you still want to remove it?

Comment: Yes. I would like to maintain the hierarchy. If even one word overflows, omit the word Custom from all `<li>`s.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668636/check-with-jquery-if-div-has-overflowing-elements   this will help you to check weather element is overflow or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one menu item text exceed the given width, below program removes all the items first word from menu. [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hrdskhxe/)

```
var items = $("#menu li a");

 items.each(function(index, item){
   if($(item)[0].offsetWidth < $(item)[0].scrollWidth){

   //remove first word in all items tabs
   items.each(function(index, item){
       $(item).text($(item).text().split(" ").splice(1,1)[0]);
   });

   //break main each loop
   return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: Just one more think. Can this be done through ajax or jquery too? I mean it I gradually decrease the width of my browser, It still works when the text exceeds the width? So that I don't have to lead the page every time? Is it possible?

Comment: I used jQuery, and this function executes only once, on DOM ready event

Answer (score 4):

Finally I've got the solution, is this the desired effect?

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/12984/)**

```
$('#menu li > a').each(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    if(element[0].offsetWidth < element[0].scrollWidth){
        $(this).text(element[0].innerText.split(' ').splice(1,1));
    }
});
```

Comment: If my text overflows like CUSTOM LANDSCA.. I want to delete CUSTOM so that only LANDSCAPE is visible..

Comment: i think link i post is help you to create this example :) +1

Comment: @NishitMaheta I used it.. But it is not working properly. Can you help me with it? You have the code too.. It works but not as per need.

Comment: @AliZia ehm, that's what this piece of code is doing right now? It checks for elements overflow and if it's true, then split the string (it's always CUSTOM ITEM) and delete the first element.

Comment: I placed it my my tpl file but it does not seem to work. Please see the page link http://metalwallart.ca/index.php?route=product/customcategory&path=165