# How to detect overflow of React component without ReactDOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically i want to be able to detect if a react component has children which are overflowing. Just as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7668692/4236924). I have found that the same thing is possible using ReactDOM, however [i cannot/should not use ReactDOM](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/678). I don't see anything on the suggested alternative,`ref`, that is equivalent.

So what i need to know is if it is possible to detect overflow within a react component under these conditions. And to the same point, is it possible to detect width at all?

Comment: Perhaps this custom hook helps: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-custom-hook-check-if-overflow/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In addition to @jered's excellent answer, i'd like to mention the qualifier that a ref will only return an element that directly has access to the various properties of regular DOM elements if the ref is placed **directly on a DOM element**. That is to say, it does not behave in this way with **Components**.

So if you are like me and have the following:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return <SomeComponent id="my-component" ref={(el) => {this.element = el}}/>
  }
})
```

and when you attempt to access DOM properties of `this.element` (probably in `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate`) and you are not seeing said properties, the following may be an alternative that works for you

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return <div ref={(el) => {this.element = el}}>
             <SomeComponent id="my-component"/>
          </div>
  }
})
```

Now you can do something like the following:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  const element = this.element;
  // Things involving accessing DOM properties on element
  // In the case of what this question actually asks:
  const hasOverflowingChildren = element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight ||
                                 element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth;
},
```

Answer (score 15):

The implementation of the solution proposed by @Jemar Jones:

```
export default class OverflowText extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      overflowActive: false
    };
  }

  isEllipsisActive(e) {
    return e.offsetHeight < e.scrollHeight || e.offsetWidth < e.scrollWidth;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ overflowActive: this.isEllipsisActive(this.span) });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          width: "145px",
          textOverflow: "ellipsis",
          whiteSpace: "nowrap",
          overflow: "hidden"
        }}
        ref={ref => (this.span = ref)}
      >
        <div>{"Triggered: " + this.state.overflowActive}</div>
        <span>This is a long text that activates ellipsis</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit 1o0k7vr1m3]

Comment: Thanks for the working code example. I found I also needed to run isEllipsisActive from componentDidUpdate, and in order to avoid infinite looping I needed to add a check before updating state: if (this.isEllipsisActive(this.span) !== this.state.overflowActive) {
   // update state here
  }

Answer (score 12):

Yep, you can use `ref`.

Read more about how `ref` works in the official documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Basically, `ref` is just a callback that is run when a component renders for the first time, immediately before `componentDidMount` is called. The parameter in the callback is the DOM element that is calling the `ref` function. So if you have something like this:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return <div id="my-component" ref={(el) => {this.domElement = el}}>Hello World</div>
  }
})
```

When `MyComponent` mounts it will call the `ref` function that sets `this.domElement` to the DOM element `#my-component`.

With that, it's fairly easy to use something like `getBoundingClientRect()` to measure your DOM elements after they render and determine if the children overflow the parent:

https://jsbin.com/lexonoyamu/edit?js,console,output

Keep in mind there is no way to measure the size/overflow of DOM elements *before* they render because by definition they don't exist yet. You can't measure the width/height of something until you render it to the screen.

Comment: Could you possibly show how something like what you showed in your jsbin with `getBoundingClientRect` would work work when the element has multiple children?

Comment: A `div` will "wrap" everything inside of it as long as they are all positioned relatively or statically. So if you put all of the `children` inside of a `div` inside of the parent (like it's structured in the jsbin) then it should work out.

Comment: If you have a more complicated use case then you should provide more detail and some examples of your code, ideally in a separate question.

Comment: Alright i actually just realized something else. In your jsbin the type of the __reactInternalInstance coming back from the refs is `ReactDOMComponent`, whereas in my similar code gives me `ReactCompositeComponentWrapper`. And this instance that i'm getting back doesn't have the same properties as yours for some reason. Would you happen to understand why?

Comment: I realized that i can actually just wrap my Component in a div in my situation, and then i am able to access the normal dom element properties! Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I needed to achieve this in React TypeScript, as such here is the updated solution in TypeScript using React Hooks. This solution will return true if there are at least 4 lines of text.

We declare the necessary state variables:

```
  const [overflowActive, setOverflowActive] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState<boolean>(false);
```

We declare the necessary ref using `useRef`:

```
  const overflowingText = useRef<HTMLSpanElement | null>(null);
```

We create a function that checks for overflow:

```
  const checkOverflow = (textContainer: HTMLSpanElement | null): boolean => {
    if (textContainer)
      return (
        textContainer.offsetHeight < textContainer.scrollHeight || textContainer.offsetWidth < textContainer.scrollWidth
      );
    return false;
  };
```

Lets build a `useEffect` that will be called when `overflowActive` changes and will check our current ref object to determine whether the object is overflowing:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (checkOverflow(overflowingText.current)) {
      setOverflowActive(true);
      return;
    }

    setOverflowActive(false);
  }, [overflowActive]);
```

In our component's return statement, we need to bind the ref to an appropriate element. I am using `Material UI` coupled with `styled-components` so the element in this example will be `StyledTypography`:

```
<StyledTypography ref={overflowingText}>{message}</StyledTypography>
```

Styling the component in `styled-components`:

```
const StyledTypography = styled(Typography)({
  display: '-webkit-box',
  '-webkit-line-clamp': '4',
  '-webkit-box-orient': 'vertical',
  overflow: 'hidden',
  textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
});
```

Answer (score 9):

The same could be achieved using React hooks:

The first thing you need would be a state which holds boolean values for *text open* and *overflow active*:

```
const [textOpen, setTextOpen] = useState(false);
const [overflowActive, setOverflowActive] = useState(false);
```

Next, you need a ref on the element you want to check for overflowing:

```
const textRef = useRef();
<p ref={textRef}>
    Some huuuuge text
</p>
```

The next thing is a function that checks if the element is overflowing:

```
function isOverflowActive(event) {
    return event.offsetHeight < event.scrollHeight || event.offsetWidth < event.scrollWidth;
}
```

Then you need a useEffect hook that checks if the overflow exists with the above function:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isOverflowActive(textRef.current)) {
        setOverflowActive(true);
        return;
    }

    setOverflowActive(false);
}, [isOverflowActive]);
```

And now with those two states and a function that checks the existence of an overflowing element, you can conditionally render some element (eg. Show more button):

```
{!textOpen && !overflowActive ? null : (
    <button>{textOpen ? 'Show less' : 'Show more'}</button>
)}
```

Answer (score 4):

To anyone who wonder how it can be done with hooks and useRef:

```
// This is custom effect that calls onResize when page load and on window resize
const useResizeEffect = (onResize, deps = []) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    onResize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", onResize);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [...deps, onResize]);
};

const App = () => {
  const [isScrollable, setIsScrollable] = useState(false);
  const [container, setContainer] = useState(null);
  // this has to be done by ref so when window event resize listener will trigger - we will get the current element
  const containerRef = useRef(container);
  containerRef.current = container;
  const setScrollableOnResize = useCallback(() => {
    if (!containerRef.current) return;
    const { clientWidth, scrollWidth } = containerRef.current;
    setIsScrollable(scrollWidth > clientWidth);
  }, [containerRef]);
  useResizeEffect(setScrollableOnResize, [containerRef]);

  return (
    <div
      className={"container" + (isScrollable ? " scrollable" : "")}
      ref={(element) => {
        if (!element) return;
        setContainer(element);
        const { clientWidth, scrollWidth } = element;
        setIsScrollable(scrollWidth > clientWidth);
      }}
    >
      <div className="content">
        <div>some conetnt</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit bv7q6]