# read more feature in CSS, ES6, react

Tags: css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to accomplish read more feature in css3, ES6 and React.

I have a very long description (this comes from the server so it's dynamic) and I would like to add 'read more' feature in this. If a description is more than 3 lines then a button/link should could us as 'read more' and when I click that button then rest of the description should be displayed.

This is my code:

React:

```
<div className="content">

Description of the product 

<button onClick=(() => {})>Read more</button>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content{
overflow: hidden;
line-height: 1.2em;
height: 3.6em;
}
```

What I am not able to figure out is when I click 'read more' button then how can change div id to make it's height to auto. 
I have the javascript code but I want to implement this in ES6

JS:

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() 
{
  document.querySelector('#content').style.height= 'auto';
this.style.display= 'none';
});
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a fiddle for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/3063/. You want to avoid directly manipulating dom when using React. The preferred approach would be to use component `state` to toggle classes on the `content` div.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
    this.description = getDescription();
    this.state = {
        expanded: false
    }
  }
    render(){
    const { expanded } = this.state;
    const toggledClass = expanded ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed';
    return(
      <div>
        <div className={`content ${toggledClass}`}>
            {this.description}
        </div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ expanded: !expanded })}>
            {expanded ? 'View Less' : 'View More'}
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

CSS

```
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  height: 3.6em;
}
.content.collapsed{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content.expanded{
  overflow: visible;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciated that. Would it be possible to do this in ES6 only?

Comment: Yeah that's all es6. What is not es6?

Comment: I was wondering whether I can do this using only ES6 and not using react state or anything else.

Comment: I guess that's up to you to refactor that out, but at that point you probably shouldn't even be using React.

Comment: seems like if the text is upto 3 lines then also 'view more' button is showing up. How can I make it invisible if the text is 3 lines and visible more than 3 lines?

Comment: You'll have to write your own JS to figure out when the div has overflow or not. Check out this post for some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668636/check-with-jquery-if-div-has-overflowing-elements