# Insert read more button when line clamping

Tags: javascript, html

I would like a read more button to appear when text overflows and to not show if the text doesn't overflow

So far I have the following code to line clamp if it overflows to line 18:

```
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 18;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
overflow: hidden;
```

I've had a thorough search and can only find solutions that toggle show more, show less when a div exceeds a certain length.

However, I would only like the button to show  if it exceeds the length: `<a href="article.html">Read more</a>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use javascript to achieve this by checking if the element has an overflow and toggle the button based on whether or not the element has an overflow.

```
function showReadMoreButton(element){
   if (element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight ||
        element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth) {
        // your element has an overflow
        // show read more button
    } else {
        // your element doesn't have overflow
    }
}

Example call:
var elementToCheck = document.getElementById('someElementToCheck');
showReadMoreButton(elementToCheck);


// call showReadMoreButton() after page load and/or window resize and/or functions which change content within the overflow element.
```

Note that you would need to call this function from the appropriate sections that could change content within the overflow element.

Reference for overflow check from:
[Check with jquery if div has overflowing elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668636/check-with-jquery-if-div-has-overflowing-elements)

Comment: If you're just using this to set a variable then the code can be simplified to: `const showBtn = element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight || element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth;`

Answer (score 3):

To solve this i used the following javascript:

```
var element = document.querySelector('.pcontent');
if( (element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight) || (element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth)){
   // your element have overflow
  document.querySelector('#read-more').style.visibility = "visible";
}
else{
  //your element don't have overflow
```

With these elements:

```
<p class="pcontent">Text here</p>
<a id="read-more" href="readmore.html">Read more</a>
```

And this css:

```
.pcontent {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 18;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
    overflow: hidden;
}
#read-more {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question but then asked myself, why do I need a "show more" button when users already see a "..." after clamping?

I ended up doing the following using [hyperscript](https://hyperscript.org/)

```html
<p class="line-clamp-4" _="on click toggle .line-clamp-4">
my very long or very short text
</p>
```

when I have in my css file

```css
.line-clamp-4 {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    /* truncate to 4 lines */
    -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
}
```

With this technique, the text will display an ending ellipsis only when it exceeds 4 lines, and clicking on the paragraph will toggle the display of the entire text. When the text occupies less than 4 lines, toggling the class has no effect.

It is possible to use more complex JS code to for example change cursor shape only when clamping happens, but I am satisfied with this simple solution.