# Check if overflow:hidden div is overflowing jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just would like to know if there is a way to check if a div with the overflow hidden attribute can be checked to see if it has content overflowing it or not. Jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

```
if (element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight ||element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth) {
     // your element have overflow
 } else {
  // your element doesn't have overflow
 }
```

or

```
if ($("#myoverflowingelement").prop('scrollWidth') > 
 $("#myoverflowingelement").width() ) {
  alert("this element is overflowing !!");  
}
else {
  alert("this element is not overflowing!!"); 
}
```

refer this link [Check with jquery if div has overflowing elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668636/check-with-jquery-if-div-has-overflowing-elements)

Comment: this did not work

Comment: I dont have a scrollheight as I am using overflow is hidden

Comment: try to give correct id to your element and element name... # means element id

Comment: Yeah, ive tried that, ive given class name

Comment: `var invisibleItems = [];
for(var i=0; i<element.childElementCount; i++){
  if (element.children[i].offsetTop + element.children[i].offsetHeight >
      element.offsetTop + element.offsetHeight ||
      element.children[i].offsetLeft + element.children[i].offsetWidth >
      element.offsetLeft + element.offsetWidth ){

        invisibleItems.push(element.children[i]);
    }

}`

Comment: Thanks for your help mate, that didn't work too, however I figured how I would do it. I manually calculated it based on the height of the internal div elements