# show the tooltip only when ellipsis is active

Tags: css

I have the next div:

```
 <div class="div-class" style="width:158px;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;" title=<%=myDesc%>
```

How can I show the tooltip only when ellipsis is active?

I find this function

```
    function isEllipsisActive(e) {
     return (e.offsetWidth < e.scrollWidth);
}
```

But I didn't know how to use it knowing I use jsp and struts

Comment: Since you set the content to be cut when it _would_ overflow, you will not _have_ any actuall overflow any more that you could check for … you would have to do that _before_ applying overflow:hidden.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML - how can I show tooltip ONLY when ellipsis is activated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474871/html-how-can-i-show-tooltip-only-when-ellipsis-is-activated)

Answer (score 13):

Try something like this:

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cgzW8/173/)
[**Working DEMO - with tooltip**](http://jsfiddle.net/cgzW8/514/)

```
$(function() {
    $('div').each(function(i) {

         if (isEllipsisActive(this))
            //Enable tooltip 
         else
            //Disable tooltip
    });
});

function isEllipsisActive(e) {
     return (e.offsetWidth < e.scrollWidth);
}
```

Comment: I have a stupid question
the $(function...) where should I put it?

Comment: How to do the same with TDs instead of DIVs? Can you make a working example about it?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using qtip (being quite popular).
First, add a class to each of your overflowing elements.

```
<span class="ellipsis-text">Some very long text that will overflow</span>
```

Then, use the jQuery selector to select multiple such elements, and apply the qTip plugin (or any other tooltip that comes to mind) on to your elements as such:

```
$('.ellipsis-text').each(function() {
    if (this.offsetWidth < this.scrollWidth) {
        $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: $(this).text()
            },
            position: {
                at: 'bottom center',
                my: 'top center'
            },
            style: {
                classes: 'qtip-bootstrap', //Any style you want
            }
        });
    }
});
```