# get text from DOM element and insert it to 'title' typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I am trying to write a directive in angular2 + typescript that makes tooltip to show only when ellipsis is active (show complete text pop up only when its not fully displayed, and ends with "..." ).
I found this answer in stackoverflow:

[show the tooltip only when ellipsis is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134192/show-the-tooltip-only-when-ellipsis-is-active)

Now I'm trying to translate this Jquery function:

To typescript. so far this is what I got:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[isEllipsisActive]' })

export class IsEllipsisActiveDirective {
constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    if (el.nativeElement.classList.contains('className')) {
         if (this.isEllipsisActive(el.nativeElement)) {
             //el.nativeElement.attributes("title",el.nativeElement.text());
         }
    }
}
 isEllipsisActive(e: any) {
return (e.offsetWidth < e.scrollWidth);
  }
}
```

I can't figure out how to get the text from the element and pass it on to the element's title using typescript. 
any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using ElementRef for direct DOM access isn't safe according to Angular2 [doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html).
You can use Renderer with ElementRef to get/set a DOM value this way:

```
import {Renderer, ElementRef} from '@angular/core;
...
export class IsEllipsisActiveDirective {
constructor {
  private _renderer: Renderer,
  private _el: ElementRef
} (
  //get value
  this._el.nativeElement.querySelector('div/p/whatever...')
  //set value
  this._renderer(_el.nativeElement.querySelector(tag), 'innerHTML', 'Foo')
)
```

Hope this helps. Credit goes to these Stack Overflow answers:

- [How do you access the element HTML from within an Angular2 attribute directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002640/how-do-you-access-the-element-html-from-within-an-angular-2-attribute-directive)
- [get hold of an element in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template)