# Scroll With != Offset Width when no Ellipsis

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to figure out whether an element has ellipsis. I am using [this stackoverflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13259660/25138)

When I test on IE the `scrollWidth` is always greater than `offsetWidth`. Even if there are no ellipsis, the `scrollWidth` is 1px greater than the `offsetWidth`. Works fine of Chrome, as expected.

Please check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/NerdPad/b2vdc9w6/2/). This will give you different values on IE and Chrome.

Is this happening due to a bug in IE? Is it a known issue? And is there a work around?

Comment: Since scrollWidth in IE is the same as in Chrome, I would say the offsetWidth is 1px smaller than the scrollWidth. Details, Shmetails.

Comment: Looks like `float: left;` is the cause. [An article about `offsetWidth` in IE](http://vadikom.com/dailies/offsetwidth-offsetheight-useless-in-ie9-firefox4/) that might be useful.

Comment: @0x2D9A3 The article helped. IE seems to be rounding up `scrollWidth` and rounding down `offsetWidth`. I am able to get the actual width (float val) using `getComputedStyle`, but can't find the actual `scrollWidth`.

Comment: Workaround answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900154/workaround-for-issue-with-ie-scrollwidth/47170414#47170414

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a an actual text ellipsis or a css one?

If text it may be better to parse the element's text for three dots at the end. Something like this:

```
function hasEllipsis(text){
    var regex = /\.\.\.$/;
    return regex.test(text);
}
```

Comment: It is clearly stated that this is a question about the `text-overflow`-property ellipsis… (And by the way, this comment has an ellipsis that your regexp won't match)

Comment: It's the css ellipsis (text-overflow)