# Move :after element onto new line on text truncation

Tags: css, html-table, whitespace, ellipsis

I am building a table that has truncated headers and content using the :after selector.

I want to be able to move the `:after` content onto a new line *only* where the header text is truncated, is there a way of doing this only using CSS?

I am currently using jQuery and `window.resize` listeners to implement a solution similar to the one found here: [HTML - how can I show tooltip ONLY when ellipsis is activated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474871/html-how-can-i-show-tooltip-only-when-ellipsis-is-activated) but would prefer to be able to do it without the extra overhead of the jQuery and the listeners

An example of the HTML and CSS is:

```
    <style>
        table, th, td {
            max-width: 75%;
            table-layout: fixed;
            border: 1px solid black;

        }

        th {
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }

        th:after {
            content: ":";
        }

    </style>


    </head>
    <body>

    <table width="600px">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="5%">I'm a very long table header that is going to get truncated in the browser</th>
        <th width="10%">small</th>
        <th width="20%">medium</th>
        <th width="65%">large</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Java</td>
        <td>01/01/2010</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>01/02/2010</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you expand your "minimal" example to be "complete" and "verifiable"? See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `:after` element content should come on next line then try following code.

```
th:after {
    content: ":";
    display:block;
    clear:both:
}
```

Comment: This would work but it would put the ":" on a new line regardless of truncation; I want the :after content on a new line only on truncation