# Show text overflow in the form of a tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got something like this.

```
<div class="someclass">
    <label data-fieldid="191366" data-val="159" class="evLabel form-control">
        Some Long Text
    </label>
</div>
```

I made it so, that if the text is too long than the overflow hides by writing `text-overflow:elipsis`, `overflow: hidden`, and `white-space:nowrap`.

I need to make it show tooltip-ish popup with the entire text (Some Long Text) on hover and possibly when it does know when this `elipsis` is actually hiding something (So, when it is necesary). How to do something like that?

Comment: What did you try regarding the tooltips?

Answer (score 3):

If you need modification in this, please comment. You can also check this [**LINK**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474871/html-how-can-i-show-tooltip-only-when-ellipsis-is-activated)

```css
div {
  line-height: 20px;
}

#data {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#data:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

#data:hover+div {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>1: ONE</div>
<div id="data">2: Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two </div>
<div>3: THREE</div>
<div>4: Four</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the Below code example :

```css
label {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<label for="x" title="Long Long Long ............... Text">Long Long Long ............... Text</label>
```

Comment: I've tried that but it's not pretty looking. I also need it to be stylised.

Comment: can you share a example of how you want it to be styled?