# SVG text overflow and tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have an svg element. In the text tag, how do i add ellipses and a tooltip when the text exceeds the width of svg using `javascript/jquery` only

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart green">
     <path class="circle-bg" d="M18 2.0845 a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831 a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />
     <path class="circle" stroke-dasharray="60, 100" d="M18 2.0845 a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831 a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />
      <text x="18" y="10.35" class="questionText">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: A function to do what you're asking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474871/html-how-can-i-show-tooltip-only-when-ellipsis-is-activated

Comment: Or calculate width of the text and if greater than the svg length, add an ellipsis. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript