# Display tooltip only when visible text ends with "..."

Tags: css, angular, angularjs, typescript, tooltip

I have a table with 5 columns and more than a thousand lines. I will only be talking about 1 column and copy the code to the others if someone here can help me to make it work.
Depending on the length of the texts in those columns, the texts can be displayed with "..." at the end of each line. This is why I added the "text-overflow: ellipsis" in the css.
What I would like, is for the tootlip (HELLO everyone) to only appear for the texts that are displayed with "..." in the end because they are too long to fit inside the column.

html (this is the code for one of the five columns of my table):

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="title">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="table-header">
    Title
  </th>
  <td 
    pTooltip="HELLO everyone" 
    (click)="toggleSeeMore(element)" 
    mat-cell 
    *matCellDef="let element" 
    class="title-column-news"
  >
    <div [style]="styleTitle(element.showSeeMore)">{{ element.title }}</div> 
      <div *ngIf="element.showSeeMore" style="margin-top: 10px">
        <span>
          <div [style]="styleTitle(element.showSeeMore)">{{ element.summary }}
            <a 
              style="color:var(--limegreen); text-decoration: none;" 
              target="_blank" 
              [href]="element.file"
            >
              See more
            </a>
          </div>
        </span>   
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

css:

```
td {
  color: var(--textLightGrey);
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--textLightGrey);
  padding: 10px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML - how can I show tooltip ONLY when ellipsis is activated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474871/html-how-can-i-show-tooltip-only-when-ellipsis-is-activated)

Comment: Not really, it's not for typescript

Comment: The logic is the same. Looks like you need to add 'mouseenter' event and check actual elemnt width.

Answer (score 0):

you can look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474871/html-how-can-i-show-tooltip-only-when-ellipsis-is-activated)

```
div {
  line-height: 20px;
}

#data {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#data:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

#data:hover+div {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

<div>1: ONE</div>
<div id="data">2: Two Two
```

```css
div {
  line-height: 20px;
}

#data {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#data:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

#data:hover+div {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>1: ONE</div>
<div id="data">2: Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two </div>
<div>3: THREE</div>
<div>4: Four</div>
```

Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two 
3: THREE
4: Four