# How do I detect the user’s browser and apply a specific CSS file?

Tags: css, user-agent

I need to detect the browser and apply the matched CSS file.

I have created 3 css files: __ie.css, ff.css, opera.css. Now I need to detect the browser in order to include the good one.

I know this

```
<!--[if IE]>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" type="text/css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

But how do I do the same with Firefox and Opera/Chrome?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have to detect browsers just to apply CSS, then you might want to rethink your CSS before going to browser-specific stylesheets.  All it takes is for one browser to mimic another's user agent string, or a new version to be released, and everything breaks.  Use the current standards and validate your code (http://validator.w3.org/), and you'll have to worry about far fewer cross-browser issues.  Even just using `<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->` without a version number could break the layout in later versions.

That being said, if you want to style the page differently based on what CSS features are available, take a look at [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/).  This way, you're only checking features, which won't be broken if a new version of the browser is released.

If all else fails and you really need to detect the visitor's browser, try `jquery.browser`.  It's built into jQuery, and is simple to use. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/.

Comment: The reason for wanting to detect browsers, is that the browsers do NOT conform to the standards correctly, particularly IE. That means fallbacks/workarounds may be necessary. But thanks for the Modernizr tip.

Comment: I understand, but browser checking is a sloppy solution to the problem. Modernizr checks for the support of **individual features**, not the existence of a particular browser. Things like modern user agent strings exist solely to fool browser checks because they often lead to broken code as the browser is updated in the future. Read this post for a better understanding of why browser detection is such a problem: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx

Comment: I agree. I just sometimes get annoyed by the compulsory if-you-need-this-feature-you-are-doing-something-wrong responses. Often there are perfectly valid reasons to initially want a feature, even if it's a bad solution. Then one could point out that there are better solutions, without implying that the poster is doing it all wrong. But I really shouldn't quarrel about this. Sorry, my bad.
Modernizr sounds cool, although the problem is often that the browser supports a feature, but implement them wrongly, which shows up in rare cases.

Comment: Referring to browser checking as a "sloppy solution" is a matter of your opinion and thus is not applicable. This should be about the best practices for a solution. I agree that modernizer is best for this case. However, overuse or the false expectation of it being the solution for all such cases is not best practice. You could have a user community with very old browsers that you don't want to support. A professional website will properly redirect that user. Feature based Modernizer is not best used for browser detection which is the best solution to redirect an unsupported browser.

Answer (score 12):

The closest you can come with pure CSS is with *feature queries*.  Instead of detecting the browser type/version, it allows you to check if a specific property/value combinations are supported by the browser.

The following is an example of using the transform property for vertical centering.  If the browser doesn't support transform, then we don't want to adjust its positioning:

```
@supports (transform: translateY(-50%)) {
    .foo {
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
}
```

[Browser support for Feature Queries](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-featurequeries)

Comment: And, of course, IE does not support "supports," which I need to use solely for IE. Fun!

Answer (score 9):

I got a requirement of adding pure CSS to show thin scrollbars in my application which should apply for every browser, so I did it in this way. This code will detect the browser and sets the style to the scrollbars in entire application.

```css
// Scroll bar css settings in global css file like styles.css

/*IE*/
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  html,
  body,
  div {
    scrollbar-face-color: #d1d8da;
    scrollbar-track-color: #dcd5d5;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #dcd5d5;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #dcd5d5;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #dcd5d5;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar; // this one will hide scroll-bars after sometime
    scrollbar-width: thin;
  }
}

/* for chrome */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #dcd5d5;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background-color: #d1d8da;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: #767979;
  }
}

/* for firefox */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  html,
  body,
  div {
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 150px;width: 400px;overflow: auto;">
<ul style="list-style-type:circle;">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: This is a neat solution.

Comment: Works perfect!!

Comment: Clear and working. Perfect!

Answer (score 3):

If you need to browser detect for Firefox, Opera and Chrome, then you're doing something wrong. The same CSS should work in all of them.

There are exceptions to this of course -- all the browsers have missing features and bugs which don't appear in the other browsers. An example would be [`text-overflow:ellipsis` which isn't supported by Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927257/text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-4).

However, if you're sticking to commonly used features, these cases are few and far between, and in general, you really shouldn't need to do browser detection these days, except for various versions of IE.

If you're not sure whether the features you want to use are supported by most browsers, you can find out at [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/) or [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

If you're using seriously cutting-edge features, then yes, you will have problems with cross-browser support. But in this case it's generally better to do feature detection, using a product like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), rather than browser detection, since this will be a more reliable way of ensuring you cover all browsers and all versions, including future versions (which is an inherent weakeness of browser detection).

Comment: @thirtydot Not necessarily, *rendering* can be fairly inconsistent regardless of *all* browsers supporting the same rules. For instance, padding might be applied differently. Right now it's happening to me and it's 2018. But still padding of `<select>` elements differs dramatically from Firefox Quantum to Chrome. Don't get me wrong, this is what I hate the most about web development. But it's a fact that is still alive ~6 years after your comment and this answer.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: There can indeed be small differences, but it's usually not too hard to work around them. If you look at the (ancient) original question, he made different CSS files for IE/Firefox/Opera, which was (and still is) a case of _doing it wrong_.

Comment: @thirtydot I fixed it by using a chrome property `-webkit-padding-start`. Which indeed feels way better than attempty to identify the browser. It simply adjusts a little bit and inconsistency that made my app look different on different browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you can use prefixed properties that each browser apply their own properties based on their prefixes and ignore others. Following code fills a background by CSS3 gradient:

```
background-color: green;
background-image: url(my-img.png);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top right, #b51111, #eeeeee);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top right, #b51111, #eeeeee);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top right, #b51111, #eeeeee);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top right, #b51111, #eeeeee);
background-image: linear-gradient(top right, #b51111, #eeeeee);
```

In this code:

- The -webkit- is for WebKit-based browsers (Chrome and Safari)
- The -moz- is for Firefox
- The -ms- is for Internet Explorer
- The -o- is for Opera

But generally speaking, browser sniffing is not the best way, because it can easily fail in newer browsers. In that way, you have to get User Agent string of the browser and parse it. Then apply specific css rules for each browser based on its supported features. If User Agent string of the browser change in newer versions, you must modify your browser sniffing code. Imagine that you want to support multiple browsers and each of them may release some new versions in one year!
You can query the browser that if it supports a given feature. e.g. HTML5 video:

```
if(!!document.createElement('video').canPlayType === true) {
// run some code that relies on HTML5 video
} else {
// do something else
}
```

There is a feature detection library named [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) that is written based on JavaScript. You can download it and include it using  in your html page. Also you must add 'no-js' class to your  element. Modernizer runs all of its feature detection tests and and some classes to  element; something like this:

```
<html lang="en-gb" class=" js no-flexbox no-flexbox-legacy canvas canvastext 
webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage websqldatabase no-indexeddb
hashchange history draganddrop no-websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs
backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity
cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients no-cssreflections csstransforms 
no-csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio  
localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg 
smil svgclippaths">
```

So, you can apply CSS rules selectively. For instance, you want to apply an animated 3D transform in supporting browsers or display something in others. Consider the following code:

```
#my-div:hover {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
```

for default case and below for alternative:

```
.no-csstransforms3d #my-div:hover {
  position: relative;
  right: 200px;
}
```

This is a good [article](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Optimizing_content_for_different_browsers:_the_RIGHT_way) describing the concept.

Answer (score 1):

There are no conditional comments for browsers other than IE.

But you can do it with javascript: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Answer (score -5):

Maybe I'm too late, but. The better solution is to use [CSS/JS Browser Determiner](https://codecanyon.net/item/cssjs-browser-determiner/3697846) (4kb minified).  **Disclaimer**: This is a ***commercial product*** that I sell.

To separate CSS and JS files, past this code to your `<html>` tag:

```
<head><script src="js/cssjs-browser-determiner.min.js"></script>

<!-- Old Browsers -->
<script>
browser.is_old && document.writeln(
  '<link href="styles/old-browser.css" rel="stylesheet">'
);
</script>
```

This file will be only loaded for old browsers (by default, those that does not support CSS3 transition). If you want to separate files for each specific browser you can do the same but change `browser.is_old` to `browser.chrome` or `browser.webkit` etc...

Then, write some CSS for specific browser inside old-browser.css (or any other CSS file):

```
.opera9 .my-el { ... }
.firefox1_5 .my-el { ... }
.ie8- .el { ... } // IE8 or less
.ios .el { ... } // iPhone, iPad, iPod
etc...
```

Comment: Downvoting.  Apparently this software was **abandoned** already a few days after this post here.  The last update is over 5 years old.  Even more evil, the live demo/documentation site no more exists at all.