# Design MC Dropdown as "Vanilla" Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have the following setup for MC Dropdown

```
<div class="mcdropdown">
<input autocomplete="off" name="" style="height: 15px; width: 159px;" id="">
<a class="mcdropdownarrow" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></div>
```

The Entries will be set during runtime via a JQuery Method.

My Question is:
How can I design the mcDropdown DIV as it would be a normal "select" Element

With Chrome / Webkit Engine it woks fine with the following CSS Code:
`-webkit-appearance: menulist;` for the class `mcdropdown`

The Arrow is showed **under** the a-Element which works fine for me.
The correspondig Command `-moz-appearance` for firefox doesn't work like expected. There the arrow doesn't show up at all. To fix this Issue I set for the `a`-Element `-moz-appearance: menulist-button;` which gave me the design of a button, but not the typical sidely attached button of a `select`-Element

In IE (**must** be compatible with IE 8) I couldn't find a solution without creating a Arrow Graphics out of a screenshot. And there is the next problem: The typically described `<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->` (i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621749/how-do-i-detect-the-user-s-browser-and-apply-a-specific-css-file)) to make a IE specific stylesheet doesn't work on my WIN7 maschine with IE10 at all.

Are there any solutions with Javascript to mimic the design of a `select`-Element in a easy way ?

My archievements until now [on codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEMprP)

Thanks for any kind of answer!

Best Regards from Frankfurt

(This is my first question on stackoverflow. I loved this plattform as passive reader and now I want to participate)