# How to apply css logic

Tags: html, css

I want different CSS for different browser.

For ex:-

i want the width to be `25.5%` in chrome and `24.4%` in IE. so what should I do

here is my html:-

```
<tr>
                <td id="flattdhist" runat="server" class="label" style="width: 25.5%; font-size: 120%;
                    font-family: Courier New; float:left;">
                    Flat status history
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Currently it is working fine for `CHROME`, but in`IE` its slightly getting disturbed. What should I do

Comment: google -media query css-

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332117/how-to-write-specific-css-for-mozilla-chrome-and-ie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to create separate stylesheet and use conditional comments for each if you need to target specific IE version.

```
<!--[if IE]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="ForIEOnly.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Please refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Detecting IE 11 is no longer supported by Microsoft via CSS.  It might be better to detect if the feature you need is available.

For example you can detect if a browser can render HTML5 video:

```
if(!!document.createElement('video').canPlayType === true) {
// run some code that relies on HTML5 video
} else {
// do something else
}
```

Here are some reference links:

[How do I detect the user’s browser and apply a specific CSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621749/how-do-i-detect-the-user-s-browser-and-apply-a-specific-css-file)

https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Optimizing_content_for_different_browsers:_the_RIGHT_way

Answer (score 0):

A pure css solution isn't available according to what i know, but if you want to use js you can do it

```
var curBrowser = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if(curBrowser.indexOf('chrome') > 0)
         document.getElementByID("eleID").style.width = "25.5%";
    else if(curBrowser.indexOf('edge') > 0)
         document.getElementByID("eleID").style.width = "24.5%";
    else
         document.getElementByID("eleID").style.width = "23.5%";
```

something like this should be possible.