# How to change font size for safari and opera but not chrome in CSS file.

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

How can i change this for one browser while having it differently for another??

```
h2 {
    font-size: 150%;
    color: red;
}
```

Thanks. like making it blue or 175% on another
The part of solution by dude below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect the user’s browser and apply a specific CSS file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621749/how-do-i-detect-the-user-s-browser-and-apply-a-specific-css-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Targeting only Firefox with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    h2 {
        font-size: 150%;
        color: red;
    } 
}
```

See it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/zLs7do58/)

See other Firefox specific css extensions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Mozilla_Extensions)

Simple writeup on 'Tricks' [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-hacks-targeting-firefox/)

**Edit**

About other browsers: You can find a lof of useful browser-specific CSS 'hacks' on [browserhacks.com](http://browserhacks.com/)

Comment: What about for opera and safari??

Comment: You can find a lof of useful browser-specific CSS 'hacks' here: http://browserhacks.com/