# How to change CSS class "width" property for different browsers i.e., IE, Chrome, Firefox?

Tags: html, css

I want to have different widths in different browsers. this i want to control with css.

Ex:

```
.className{ width: 100px; }
```

but for chrome
Ex:

```
.className{ width: 110px; }
```

for mozilla
Ex:

```
.className{ width: 120px; }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its not a good practice to having different css based on browser.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621749/how-do-i-detect-the-user-s-browser-and-apply-a-specific-css-file

Comment: @Sumit Gulati, I want to have in same class name in same file.

Comment: Finding ways to target specific browsers or browser versions is discouraged because: a) there's no fail-proof method of getting current browser and version; b) whatever works today will not work tomorrow. You can't keep such a practice up to date. So your current approach will fail. It's not a matter of ***if***, but ***when*** and ***how often***. It is a lot easier to find the reason why you need to have different widths in different browsers and fix that.

Comment: @Manoj Check the above comment by Andrei and refer the link. Find better way to solve the issue. The above solution can break anytime on different version of same browser.

Comment: Not recommended, though this site have everything you need: http://browserhacks.com/

Comment: It is not good practice to do so, and please give us code example of yours when you asking for question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** I know using browser-specific CSS is highly discouraged but this is to answer the question - in case someone else needs this, and specifically this.

Without using JavaScript, I know you can target Internet Explorer and Firefox (Chrome-only seems plausable) but I have my doubts about the Safari method.

**Internet Explorer**: (https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

HTML (yes, it's meant to be commented out):

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Google Chrome (and Safari or other Webkit)**

I forgot to get the URL... sorry

```
/* Chrome, Safari, AND NOW ALSO the Edge Browser and Firefox */
@media and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  /* CSS CODE */
}

/* Chrome 29+ */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
  and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
    /* CSS CODE */
}

/* Chrome 22-28 */
@media screen and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  .selector {-chrome-:only(; 
     /* CSS CODE */
  );} 
}
```

**Safari Only - Questionable**

This one apparently works with Safari 9.0+ but I'm not that sure about this one. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23948854/2872279

```
.yourClass:not(:root:root){ 
    /* ^_^ */ 
}
```

**Mozilla Firefox**

[Targeting only Firefox with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css)

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    /* CSS Code */
}
```

**If you are using JavaScript, I'd recommend just using this tool (I didn't look into it that much but I believe it uses the User Agent):
http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/**

Otherwise, you could just use PHP or some other language and get it by user agent.

**Another Edit:** I've just noticed that someone has also posted a nice hacks list for CSS - so I'll refer you to their answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4332138/2872279

Comment: No problem :) @Manoj

Answer (score 0):

Using browser specific css is highly discouraged.

Instead there are other methods of adapting your styling to different environments. The use of `100px` in a property like width is problematic. If you want a part of your application to be at some width you can do one of the following:

1. Use relative units like `50%` or `1.2em` etc'. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) is a great place to start reading about relative css units.
2. Use [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
3. Use one of the many grid systems out there. Most of them allow you to split the screen to a logical rows and columns and then specify how is your element is placed on the grid. For example here is [bootstrap's](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/) grid system.