# How do you make table cells show as much text as fits in one line, like GMail and Google Reader?

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to make a table (not necessarily using the table tag) where each row has a fixed height and fills the entire available horizontal space and one of the columns has a dynamic width that shows as much text as possible without line breaking? Like Gmail and Google Reader.

I really like that way of presenting information. The expandable fixed height row is a good way to scan through a list of data, IMHO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/gtRnn/

```
<p>What is the best way *snip*</p>

p {
    border: 1px dashed #666;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis
}
```

Each property is doing something useful:

- `white-space: nowrap` forces the text to stay on one line.
- `overflow: hidden` stops [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gtRnn/1/).
- `text-overflow: ellipsis` works in "all browsers", [*except*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927257/text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-4) Firefox ([support is planned](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=312156))
- `border` is there for no reason.

Comment: +1 for the `text-overflow`, although not 100% browser compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer!

Answer (score 4):

The other answers don't work within a table as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/gtRnn/8/ - The link also contains the right way to do it.

The solution is to set the **table-layout** style on the table to **fixed** and to give each column a percent or absolute width. **table-layout: fixed;** tells the browser not to calculate the table's width based on the contents but from explicit widths given to each cell.

**Working Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/gtRnn/8/

**Code:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .my-table {
        /* This is important for ellipsis to work in tables.
           Don't forget to explicitly set the widths on all columns. */
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;              /* The table must be given a width. */
    }

    .overflow-ellipsis {
        overflow: hidden;        /* Ellipsis won't work without this. */
        text-overflow: ellipsis; /* The most important part */
    }
</style>

<table border="1" class="my-table">
    <tr>
        <td width="10%">1.</td>
        <td width="90%" class="overflow-ellipsis">
            In this TD, wrapping still occurs if there is white space.
            ButIfThereIsAReallyLongWordOrStringOfCharactersThenThisWillNotWrapButUseEllipsis
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="10%">2.</td>
        <td width="90%" class="overflow-ellipsis" style="white-space:nowrap;">
            In this TD, wrapping will not occur, even if there is white space.
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Mixing percent widths and absolute width's doesn't work correctly (in Google Chrome at least).

Answer (score 2):

The key being the `overflow: hidden;` and the `white-space: nowrap;`

```
<div style="width: 200px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">some long text.............asdfasdf........</div>
```