# css overflow - only 1 line of text

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have `div` with the following css style:

```
width:335px; float:left; overflow:hidden; padding-left:5px;
```

When I insert, into that `div`, a long line of text, it's breaking to a new line and displays all the text.  What I want is to have only one line of text that will not line-break.  When the text is long, I want this overflowing text to disappear.

I was thinking about setting the height but it seems to be wrong.

Maybe if I add height that is the same as the font, it should work and not cause any problems in different browsers?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 477, accepted):

If you want to restrict it to one line, use `white-space: nowrap;` on the div.

Comment: But then it doesn't show the ellipsis if the text goes beyond the dimension specified. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342411/how-to-display-an-image-next-to-some-texts

Comment: It works, great. But I need `...` if there are more character to show because when length of line long and it goes out of written div.

Comment: This acts weird if the hidden text contains hyper links.  If I were to tab through the page it would cause the link in the hidden text to scroll onto the screen, when it should be hidden.

Comment: The overflow styles need to be applied to the innermost block or inline-block element.  And if you have an inline-block, you'll need `max-width: 100%` on that.

Comment: You may also need `max-width: 100%` on some containing elements.  I don't have time to produce an example, so can't post an answer.

Answer (score 93):

If you want to indicate that there's still more content available in that div, you may probably want to show the "ellipsis":

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

This should be in addition to `white-space: nowrap;` suggested by Septnuits.

Also, make sure you checkout [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927257/text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-4-and-ff5) to handle this in Firefox.

Comment: I believe you must use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` with `overflow: hidden;` and `white-space: nowrap;` to make it work

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-overflow aka. yes, you can. Consider putting the whole content in the title attribute, so the user has still access to it.

Comment: mine just shows in one line and doesn't populate the DIV before showing the ellipsis... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342411/how-to-display-an-image-next-to-some-texts (http://jsfiddle.net/ofrj55j4/20/)

Answer (score 75):

You can use this css code:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis; 
overflow: hidden; 
white-space: nowrap;
```

The **text-overflow** property in CSS deals with situations where text is clipped when it overflows the element's box. It can be **clipped** (i.e. cut off, hidden), display an **ellipsis** ('…', Unicode Range Value U+2026).

Note that **text-overflow** only occurs when the container's overflow property has the value **hidden**, **scroll** or **auto** and **white-space: nowrap;**.

Text overflow can only happen on **block** or **inline-block** level elements, because the element needs to have a width in order to be overflow-ed. The overflow happens in the direction as determined by the direction property or related attributes.

Answer (score 18):

the best code for UX and UI is

```
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
display: inherit;
```

Answer (score 11):

I was able to achieve this by using the `webkit-line-clamp` and the following css:

```css
div {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: `line-clamp` doesn't have great support across browsers though: https://caniuse.com/?search=line-clamp

Comment: @AlexandervanOostenrijk Support seems fine now, does this way have any down or upsides compaired to the nowrap-ellipiss option?

Answer (score 10):

```
width:200px;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
```

Define width also to set overflow in one line

Answer (score 10):

I solved it by using:

> ```
> white-space: nowrap;
> overflow: hidden;
> text-overflow: ellipsis;
> ```

```css
.txt1{width:100px;}
.txt2{width:200px;}
.mytext{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="txt1 mytext">
A B C D E F G H I K L M N O P Q R S T V X Y Z
</div>
<div class="txt2 mytext">
A B C D E F G H I K L M N O P Q R S T V X Y Z
</div>
<div class="txt3 ">
A B C D E F G H I K L M N O P Q R S T V X Y Z
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if addition please, if you have a long text please you can use this css code bellow;

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: visible;
white-space: nowrap;
```

make the whole line text visible.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, If you want it to be one line tall, use `white-space: nowrap;` on the div or list. Whatever you are using it for it should work.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue and I solved it by using:

```
display: inline-block;
```

on the `div` in question.