# Horizontal Dropdown Menu not showing two words in one line

Tags: html, css

I am making a horizontal dropdown menu on wordpress but my dropdown menu is showing only one word in one line. I am trying to set it but failed. Using following code

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation ps-nav " role="navigation">
<div class="nav-wrapper">
<div class="menu-main-menu-container">
<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-289" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-289">
<a href="/work">work</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-288" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-51 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-288"><a href="/office">office</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-292" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-292"><a href="#">profile</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-293" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom   menu-item-293"><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-294" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-294"><a href="#">people</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-287" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-287"><a href="/contact">contact</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>

<style>

.main-navigation {
text-align: center;
line-height: 1;
}
.menu-main-menu-container {
float: right !important;
}
ul {
list-style: none;
}
body {
background: black;
}
ul, ol {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
ul, menu, dir {
display: block;
list-style-type: disc;
margin-block-start: 1em;
margin-block-end: 1em;
margin-inline-start: 0px;
margin-inline-end: 0px;
padding-inline-start: 40px;
}
.main-navigation ul li {
margin-left: 25px;
line-height: 18px;
position: relative;
float: left;
font-weight: 900;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 30px;
letter-spacing: 0px;
text-transform: lowercase;
}

li {
display: list-item;
text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

.main-navigation ul li a {
padding: 4px 0px 15px 4px;
}
.main-navigation ul li a {
color: #ffffff;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
}
a {
background-color: transparent;
}
.main-navigation ul ul {
min-width: 180px;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
margin: 30px 0 0;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.current-menu-item ul, .current-menu-parent ul {
DISPLAY: unset !important;
opacity: unset !important;
background-color: transparent !important;
visibility: visible !important;
margin-top: 5px !important;
right: 0px !important;
left: unset !important;
}
.main-navigation ul ul.sub-menu li, .main-navigation ul ul.children li {
float: unset !important;
display: table-cell;
border-left: 11px solid transparent;
}
.main-navigation ul ul.sub-menu li, .main-navigation ul ul.children li {
width: unset !important;
}
.main-navigation ul ul.sub-menu li, .main-navigation ul ul.children li {
margin: 0;
padding-left: 5px;
position: relative;
}
.main-navigation ul ul.sub-menu a, .main-navigation ul ul.children a {
color: white;
display: block;
font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly8Um/441/)

I want to show in one row in dropdown. You can check Contact Us where us is showing under the contact word. Please let me know the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're saying then the solution could be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7546415/10338004).

```
.main-navigation ul li {
    /* ... */
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ly8Um/450/)

Comment: Yes you really understand what I wanted to ask. Issue solved Thanks