# The size (width) of text in different browsers

Tags: javascript, fonts, cross-browser

I need to fit text in div box with exact width.
Is there a way (for example with javascript) to make the text look the same size in all major browsers?
For example strip some letters if text does not fit 'div' box.

Comment: There is always CSS overflow hidden.

Comment: This is not suitable for me. Overflow hidden can cut letters in the middle.

Comment: @pi11: What do you mean in "strip some letters if text does not fit 'div' box"?

Comment: Like this - "This is some tex..."

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following properties to the CSS rule for your div:

```
overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;
```

You can [see this in action here (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/qbgHx/).

Comment: Nice. Unfortunately my FF4 does not support text-overflow:ellipsis;

Comment: @pi11 - yes, this is a well known FF problem (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927257/text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-4-and-ff5). Supposedly FF7 finally supports ellipsis...

Answer (score 0):

First of, set your font face and size with css. Then you will almost always have the same width.

Then you can add overflow: hidden; to your div so it won't show anything that goes past the end.

Depending on how you're doing this, you could use padding and margins without setting a width, that way it will always fit in the div. Although this may not be what you want.

Comment: I set font face and size. But text look difference in FF and Chrome (width). Here is example - http://imghs.com/i/NeZvKsiBVRbf/

Comment: May I ask what your page layout is? There is likely a better way to support different text widths. Maybe set the width to more than is need and center the text?

Comment: In my case texts are from user-input. So size of them are always different. I can truncate letters with python before output, but I need to fill whole div box with text. And I can't estimate exact font width.

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate your text with CSS or with JavaScript. Here's an example of a simple JQuery truncation plugin I wrote which allows for a "show more" link if the text is truncated:

```
$.fn.trunc = function(_break_at) {

    var _article = jQuery(this).text();
    var _leader = [];
    var _trailer = [];
    var _substr = _article.split(' ');
    $(this).wrapInner('<div class="long"></div>');

    $.each(_substr, function(i, data) {
        if (i < _break_at) {
            _leader.push(data);
        }
    });

    if (_substr.length > _break_at) {

        $('<div/>').addClass('short').html(_leader.join(' ')).prependTo(this);
        $('<span/>').appendTo('.long').addClass('toggle').html(' &lt;&lt; Show less');
        $('<span/>').appendTo('.short').addClass('toggle').html('... Show more &gt;&gt;');

    }
    $('.toggle').click(function() {
        $('.short, .long').toggle('show');
    });
};

$(function() {

    // This is how you use it
    $('#article_body').trunc(2);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/7ZamJ

Comment: Thanks, but how estimate _break_at value for each line of text? For example this text - "lllllll" and this text - "WWWWWW" take different width (if used not monospace font).