# How to handle text overflow. Is there a Firefox equivalent to the text-overflow style from IE and Safari?

Tags: html, css

I would like to give some kind of indication to the user when text has overflowed and is too large for a container.

I'm using overflow:hidden so, there is a chance that some text will not be visible and I want to find a way to let the user know when/if this happens.

The text-overflow style would work for this but FireFox does not support it.

Update:
Credit to @Galled for this link: [text-overflow:ellipsis in Firefox 4? (and FF5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927257/text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-4-and-ff5) which shows how to emulate text-overflow:ellipsis in older versions of FireFox.

Looks like text-overflow:ellipsis is working in the more recent version of FireFox as explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-overflow#Browser_compatibility

Update:
I really like this JavaScript solution ( [Determine if an HTML element's content overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143815/how-to-determine-using-javascript-if-html-element-has-overflowing-content/143889#143889) ). Of course, using JavaScript will give you a lot more control over how overflowed content is displayed though I was looking for a pure HTML/CSS solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-overflow#Browser_compatibility), Firefox has support to text-overflow (but in version 7.0).

I make a simple test, and in Firefox 6.0 works flawed:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
p {  
  white-space: nowrap;  
  width: 100%;                     
  overflow: hidden;              /* "overflow" value must be different from "visible" */   

  text-overflow:    ellipsis;  
}  

div{
    width:30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body >
<div>
<p>Hello, hello, hello, hello, hello, hello, hello, hello, hello, hello</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using Firefox 5.0 (haven't updated yet due to plugin conflicts). I made a fiddle to check it:http://jsfiddle.net/g3un2/ So Firefox 6.0 works ok then. Cool.

Comment: If you mean the support to `text-overflow:ellipsis` Firefox has no support to this, but you can see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927257/text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-4-and-ff5) to see how emulate it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-overflow#Browser_compatibility - According to this, text-overflow isn't supported until FF7.

Answer (score 0):

I think the CSS property you're looking for is [overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

[But since you don't say exactly what you're trying to do I can't be positive.]

Comment: Overflow just chops off whatever doesn't fit. This does not indicate to the user that something has been chopped off. Consider text that is 3 lines but the container it is in only has enough room for 2. 1 line disappears and the user has no idea.