# Simplest way to truncate string w/jQuery

Tags: jquery, truncate

I have a page that is currently utilizing a [jQuery plug-in](https://github.com/tagedieb/jquery-truncate/blob/master/jquery.truncate.js) for truncating text string based on a width provided. While the string is truncated and ends with "..." the full string is placed inside TITLE of the element.

Normally it works great, however, I noticed a case where a page has too many strings, close to 100, and my page starts crashing, complaining that the script stopped responding.

Is there a simpler way to truncate? I'm OK use approximate width, perhaps switching to a character count?

I'd love it if this could be accomplished with just a few lines of code.

Can something like this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called ellipsis. I would suggest you to go for css rather than using JavaScript.

Something like this.

```
.ellipsis {
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow:ellipsis;
    -moz-binding:url('ellipsis.xml');
}
```

Where `ellipsis.xml` contains

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bindings 
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
  xmlns:xbl="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
  xmlns:xul="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
     <binding id="ellipsis">
        <content>
           <xul:window>
              <xul:description crop="end" xbl:inherits="value=xbl:text"><children/></xul:description>
           </xul:window>
        </content>
     </binding>
</bindings>
```

Also for browsers like FF(4 to 7) which do not support ellipsis there are workarounds to achieve this.

You can take a look at this link for FF workarounds [text-overflow:ellipsis in Firefox 4? (and FF5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927257/text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-4-and-ff5)

Comment: But this will add ellipsis to all strings, right? Some of my strings are shorter than the space allocated.

Comment: It will apply based on the width of the container on which it is applied. If the string is short enough to fit in it then it will not show ellipsis.

Comment: I don't see a width in the class. Where would I specify it? Are there any examples that I can take a look at?

Comment: @santa - Take a look at this link http://www.visibilityinherit.com/code/ellipsis.php. There are coupld of demos.

Comment: Won't it cut in the middle of a letter, if the width limit is reached?

Comment: It will show `...` if it cuts in the middle of a word. What do you expect?

Comment: I did not mean in the middle of a work. It will cut in the middle of any letter.

Comment: You can try and see it will not.

Comment: OK, I'm willing to try. But what's in ellipsis.xml? Where do I get it?

Comment: Thanks. I am testing. Oddly enough I can't apply the class to the <td>. In order for it to work I have to wrap string with the <div>. Regardless, I think this is going to be a lot faster than running each through jQuery plugin. Thanks for the suggestion!