# HTML / CSS Ellipsis (...) Not Working

Tags: html, css, text, overflow, ellipsis

I'm attempting to get ellipsis working on my site. This is the following HTML / CSS code and it doesn't appear to be working.

CSS:

```
.oneline {
text-overflow:ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="oneline">Testing 123 Testing 456 Testing 789</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using a CSS3 compliant browser?

Comment: Check out this answer if you're on FF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927257/text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-4-and-ff5

Comment: Looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/ZBQnL/

Comment: Working fine in latest versions of Chrome, FF, and IE9

Comment: This shouldn't even need a CSS3 compatible browser - even IE6 renders `white-space:nowrap` and `text-overflow:ellipsis` correctly.

Comment: Managed to fix it by styling the paragraph rather than the whole div.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the [initial post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10762424/revisions), we're all assuming the obvious, but just in case ... ;)

```
<style type="text/css">
    .oneline {
        text-overflow : ellipsis;
        white-space   : nowrap;
        width         : 50px;
        overflow      : hidden;
    }
</style>
<div class="oneline">Testing 123 Testing 456 Testing 789</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NawcT/

**EDIT**: Solution was to style the paragraph vs the div.

Comment: Seems to work fine on jsfiddle.net - I have the styling in a separate stylesheet.

Comment: Are you using multiple stylesheets? Maybe you have a resetter which is  clobbering your `text-overflow` or `overflow` rules. You can try adding `!important` after the rule assignments to test that theory.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning `position:absolute` to the element to be truncated will probably have less undesired side-effects that `float:left`.

This worked for me:

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```