# How to check if Text-overflow:ellipsis is supported in browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, ellipsis

I would like to check supportability for the ellipsis overflow , not by querying the browser type or version. Is that possible?

I know that firefox versions < 7 are not supporting this.

thanks,
Tal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't try such approach but this may work:

```
function checkEllipsis() {
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  if(typeof d.style.textOverflow == 'undefined')
    return false;
  d.style.textOverflow = 'ellipsis';
    return d.style.textOverflow == 'ellipsis';
}
```

Comment: Interesting...i'll try that one.   question is whether unsupported browsers may take the textOverflow but not use it.

Answer (score 1):

CanIUse is a very helpful site for checking browser support - http://caniuse.com/#search=ellipsis.

Don't know how you can test if a browser supports something without testing which browser it is?! [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927257/text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-4-and-ff5) covers a similar topic and may be of use.