# define an override to onRowFocus in sports.ux.grid.GridView

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, extjs, backbone.js

- I am trying to define an override to onRowFocus in 
  sports.ux.grid.GridView.
- In the override, I should check a new config to the grid panel and
  set supressFocus, then call the super.onRowFocus
- not sure how to check the  new config to the grid panel
- did some research and not sure how to update the code in my new
  method,
- can you guys tell me how to update my code

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.View

providing my code below

```
/**
 * @ignore
 * @method createAutoTip - Helper method to create a tooltip which shows 
 *     itself only when the element's contents cannot fully be seen.
 *
 * @param  tooltipElementId the id of the element 
 */
sports.ux.grid.createAutoTip = function (tooltipElementId) {
    return Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip',{
        target: tooltipElementId.el,
        delegate: ':any(.x-grid-cell-inner|.x-grid-hd-inner)',
        bodyCls: 'sports-grid-tooltip',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        listeners: {
            beforeshow: function updateTipBody(tip) {
                var trigger = tip.triggerElement;
                //
                // Idea for scrollWidth>offsetWidth check got from this link:
                // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927257/text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-4
                // 
                var s = Ext.query("[skiptip=true]", trigger);
                if (!Ext.isEmpty(s) || trigger.scrollWidth <= trigger.offsetWidth) {
                    //tip.body.dom.innerHTML = '';
                    return false; // don't show tip
                }
                tip.body.dom.innerHTML = trigger.innerHTML;
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
};

/**
 * GridView extension supporting following features:
 * 
 * * sports-value column headers.
 * * Hide sorting options if column is not sortable, instead of just disabling them.
 * 
 * This is used by {@link sports.ux.grid.GridPanel}.
 */
Ext.define('sports.ux.grid.GridView', {
    extend : 'Ext.grid.View',    
    alias: 'widget.sports.ux.gridview',
    mixins: {
        gridviewcompositecolumn: 'sports.ux.grid.GridViewCompositeColumn'
    },

    requires: [
        'sports.util.MessageBox'
    ],

    /**
     * @cfg
     * Text shown for the "sports-value header" popup menu tied to columns of a grid.
     */
    sports-valueHeaderText: 'sports-value header',
    /**
     * @cfg
     * Text shown for the title of the popup prompt used to enter the new column header. 
     */
    sports-valuePromptTitleText: 'sports-value column heading',

    /**
     * @cfg
     * Text shown for the label next to the input box on the popup prompt 
     * used to enter the new column name.
     */
    sports-valuePromptMsgText: 'Enter new column heading name',

    /**
     * @cfg
     * Message to display when the name of the column is not unique among 
     * the other columns.
     */
    sports-valueFailedText: 'sports-value failed: a column with header "{0}" already exists!',

    /**
     * @cfg
     * Flag to control if we hide the Sort Ascending/Sort Descending when the column isn't sortable.
     * Defaults to `true`.
     */
    hideIfNotSortable: true,

    /**
     * @cfg {Boolean} restrictsports-value
     * Specify `true` to restrict renaming column headers for this grid. Defaults to `false`.
     */
    restrictsports-value: false,    

    //@private
    error_title: 'Error - Grid Component',
    enableTextSelection: true,


    constructor: function(config){
        Ext.apply(this, config);

        this.headerCt.addEvents({
            /**
             * @event columnsports-value
             * @param {Ext.grid.header.Container} ct The grid's header Container which encsportsulates all column headers.
             * @param {Ext.grid.column.Column} column The Column header Component which provides the column definition
             * @param {String} new text
             */
            columnsports-value: true
        });

        sports.ux.grid.GridView.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments);

        // Settings from this point cannot be changed from outside

        // Allow us to add the sports-value menu.
        this.headerCt.on('menucreate', this.onMenuCreate, this);
    },

    /**
     * @private create the menu before it is shown
     * @param {Object} headerCt
     * @param {Object} menu
     */
    onMenuCreate: function(headerCt, menu) {
        menu.on('show', this.onMenuShow, this);
    },


    //updating my method 

    onRowFocus:function(){
        console.log("here- on row focus");

        //check a new config to the grid panel and 
        this.callParent();

        //set supressFocus, then call the super.onRowFocus
        this.callSuper();
    }

});
```

Comment: How does this have anything to do with jquery, angular, or backbone?

Comment: @keizom I thought general js developers can help me out