# text-overflow: ellipsis property not working for IE11 browser

Tags: html, css

The following css works and display the ellipsis (highlighted in red color) in case of Chrome browser with results as mentioned below:

Chrome:

```
position: relative;
display: -webkit-box;
max-height: 136px;
-webkit-line-clamp: 4;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Result:

[image]

But in case of IE 11 it is not displaying the ellipsis :

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Tested and it seems to work just fine: https://jsbin.com/zaxasamoxa/1/edit

```css
h1 {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-box;
  max-height: 136px;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 4px;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<h1>absdfmksdlfmdlskflsdkfmlsdkmflskdmf</h1>
```

Check your CSS for other rules that might me messing things around.

Note that `display: -webkit-box;` will break the ellipsis in chrome.

Support also confirmed by https://caniuse.com/#feat=text-overflow

[image]

Comment: On visiting the url I am seeing a different response. I tried it multiple times but I see absdfm as the response for both Chrome and IE browser.

Comment: Did it worked for you? I tried multiple times and found not working. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, it worked for me. 1st you should check the IE version. You could also try to remove every other css property and check if it works. If it don't,  then there's no support; else you can add each css at a time to find out what is causing the issue

Comment: I have IE 11 (Version:11.706.17134.0C0) in my system. I tried the url ; https://jsbin.com/zaxasamoxa/1/edit for both chrome and IE11 and did not see the expected response.

Comment: So we can conclude that the support is inconsistent and you should find some kind of polyfil. Check out this answer's JS snippets https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927257/text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-4-and-ff5